# Modify sliderInput legend

Tags: r, date, shiny, slider

To select a certain period of time, I use the following sliderInput:

[SliderInput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Enx4H.png)

In the 'legend' below, I would like to display only dates every five days so in this case '2016-06-01', '2016-06-06', '2016-06-11', '2016-06-16' etc...

I have not found any possibility to do this in the documentation or on forums.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/sliderInput.html

```
step
```

Specifies the interval between each selectable value on the slider (if NULL, a heuristic is used to determine the step size). `If the values are dates, step is in days`; if the values are times (POSIXt), step is in seconds.

Comment: Maybe my problem was not very clear, I want to be able to select any date, I just want to change the display below the bar.
From what I understand, step diminishes the values I can select and I want to be able to select any of them.

Comment: maybe you should use https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/dateInput.html instead of your slider i know it's not what you are asking but it's lot better to use with date format